# How to use websockets in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sockets

I'm trying to integrate web sockets into my Rails application as per this link: https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/wiki/Installation-and-Setup

I use Ruby 2.0 and Rails3.
The contents of the relevant files:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'websocket-rails
```

events.rb

```
WebsocketRails::EventMap.describe do
subscribe :awesomeness_approval, :to => ChatController, :with_method =>   :awesomeness_approval
end
```

development.rb

...
    config.middleware.delete Rack::Lock
...

chat_controller.rb

```
class ChatController < WebsocketRails::BaseController
def initialize_session
# perform application setup here
controller_store[:message_count] = 0
end

def awesomeness_approval
if message[:awesomeness] > 5
trigger_success {:m => 'awesome level is sufficient'}
else
trigger_failure {:m => 'awesome level is insufficient'}
end
end
end
```

chat.js

```
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('localhost:3000/websocket');
dispatcher.on_open = function(data) {
  console.log('Connection has been established: ', data);
}

var success = function(response) {
  console.log("You are awesome because: "+response.message);
}

var failure = function(response) {
  console.log("You are not very awesome because: "+response.message);
}

var message = { awesomeness: 4 }
dispatcher.trigger('awesomeness_approval', message, success, failure);
```

When I try to start rails server, I get the following error:

```
w/app/controllers/chat_controller.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
    trigger_success {:m => 'awesome level is sufficient'}
```

...

```
/app/controllers/chat_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
    trigger_failure {:m => 'awesome level is insufficient'}
```

However, if I comment out the above lines, I'm able to start the server, and the browser is able to connect to the web socket.  The following output is seen on browser console:

```
"Connection has been established: " Object { connection_id: "f66c4298eb103312e181" } chat.js:3
```

Please help.

Comment: What is trigger_failure and trigger_success supposed to be there? A hash object? A method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from a syntax ambiguity in your method call.

When you write

```
trigger_success {:m => 'awesome level is sufficient'}
```

the opening curly brace is interpreted to be the start of a block argument to the method. However, you intend it to be a hash. Interpreted as a block, it would indeed be wrong syntax as a block doesn't allow a simple hash rocket.

You can resolve this ambiguity, you can use parenthesis:

```
trigger_success({:m => 'awesome level is sufficient'})
```

That way, it is clear for the ruby parser that you actually mean to pass a single hash argument to the method and is currently parsed.